# Is there a way to represent JSON data as a graph structure using VueJS and typescript on a canvas?

Tags: json, typescript, vuejs3

I have a canvas in VueJS and JSON data which I need to represent as a graph structure. This graph will have nodes and edges. The nodes in this case are the tables as shown in the JSON like `people`, `person_addresses` etc and the edges are the tables in the edges part of the JSON. The JSON is below defined as a constant with properties like hardcoded positions to position on the canvas:

```
 const branch = {
nodes: {
    people: {
        "label": "people",
        "color": "green",
        "fixed": true,
        "icon": "\uf0c0",
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.2), "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.5)},
        "columns": [
            "person_id",
        ]
    },
    person_addresses: {
        "label": "person_addresses",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": false,
        "icon": "\uf2b9",
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.06), "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.4)},
        "columns": [
            "person_id",
        ]
    },
    person_names: {
        "label": "person_names",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": false,
        "icon": "\uf2b9",
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.06), "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.85)},
        "columns": [
            "person_id",
        ]
    },
    person_types: {
        "label": "person_types",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": false,
        "icon": "\uf509",
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.06), "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.7)},
        "columns": [
            "person_type_id"
        ]
    },
    person_has_type: {
        "label": "person_has_type",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": false,
        "icon": "\ue541",
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.06), "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.55)},
        "columns": [
            "person_id",
            "person_type_id"
        ]
    },
    de_identified_identifiers: {
        "label": "de_identified_identifiers",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": false,
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.06), "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.25)},
        "columns": [
            "person_id",
        ]
    },
    identifiers: {
        "label": "identifiers",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": false,
        "icon": "\uf2c2",
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.06), "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.1)},
        "columns": [
            "person_id",
        ]
    },
    occupation: {
        "label": "occupation",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": false,
        "icon": "\uf2bb",
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.2), "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.85)},
        "columns": [
            "person_id",
        ]
    },
    contact_details: {
        "label": "contact_details",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": false,
        "icon": "\uf2c2",
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.25), "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.7)},
        "columns": [
            "person_id",
        ]
    },
    hiv_staging_infos: {
        "label": "hiv_staging_infos",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": false,
        "icon": "\ue076",
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.35), "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.85)},
        "columns": [
            "person_id",
        ]
    },
    soundexes: {
        "label": "soundexes",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": false,
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.35), "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.7)},
        "columns": [
            "person_id",
        ]
    },
    potential_duplicates: {
        "label": "potential_duplicates",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": false,
        "icon": "\uf0c5",
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.35), "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.25)},
        "columns": [
            "person_id",
        ]
    },
    outcomes: {
        "label": "outcomes",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": false,
        "icon": "\uf681",
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.2), "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.1)},
        "columns": [
            "person_id",
        ]
    },
    relationships: {
        "label": "relationships",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": false,
        "icon": "\uf067",
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.35), "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.1)},
        "columns": [
            "person_id",
        ]
    },
    de_duplicator: {
        "label": "de_duplicator",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": false,
        "icon": "\uf24d",
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.2), "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.25)},
        "columns": [
            "person_id",
        ]
    },
    encounters: {
        "label": "encounters",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": true,
        "icon": "\uf0f0",
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.6) + seperator, "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.75)},
        "columns": [
            "person_id",
            "encounter_id"
        ]
    },
    master_definitions: {
        "label": "master_definitions",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": true,
        "icon": "\uf02d",
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.6) + seperator, "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.06)},
        "columns": [
            "master_definition_id",
        ]
    },
    hts_results_given: {
        "label": "hts_results_given",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": false,
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.45) + seperator, "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.85)},
        "columns": [
            "encounter_id",
        ]
    },
    family_plannings: {
        "label": "family_plannings",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": false,
        "icon": "\ue537",
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.55) + seperator, "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.85)},
        "columns": [
            "encounter_id",
        ]
    },
    pregnant_statuses: {
        "label": "pregnant_statuses",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": false,
        "icon": "\ue31e",
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.65) + seperator, "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.85)},
        "columns": [
            "encounter_id",
        ]
    },
    appointments: {
        "label": "appointments",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": false,
        "icon": "\uf2b5",
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.75) + seperator, "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.85)},
        "columns": [
            "encounter_id",
        ]
    },
    vitals: {
        "label": "vitals",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": false,
        "icon": "\uf21e",
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.45) + seperator, "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.15)},
        "columns": [
            "encounter_id",
            "master_definitions_id"
        ]
    },
    patient_histories: {
        "label": "patient_histories",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": false,
        "icon": "\uf487",
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.45) + seperator, "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.3)},
        "columns": [
            "encounter_id",
            "master_definitions_id"
        ]
    },
    presenting_complaints: {
        "label": "presenting_complaints",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": false,
        "icon": "\uf481",
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.45) + seperator, "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.45)},
        "columns": [
            "encounter_id",
            "master_definitions_id"
        ]
    },
    diagnosis: {
        "label": "diagnosis",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": false,
        "icon": "\uf0f1",
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.45) + seperator, "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.6)},
        "columns": [
            "encounter_id",
            "master_definitions_id"
        ]
    },
    symptoms: {
        "label": "symptoms",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": false,
        "icon": "\ue061",
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.55) + seperator, "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.3)},
        "columns": [
            "encounter_id",
            "master_definitions_id"
        ]
    },
    breastfeeding_statuses: {
        "label": "breastfeeding_statuses",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": false,
        "icon": "\ue53a",
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.55) + seperator, "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.15)},
        "columns": [
            "encounter_id",
            "master_definitions_id"
        ]
    },
    side_effects: {
        "label": "side_effects",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": false,
        "icon": "\ue064",
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.55) + seperator, "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.6)},
        "columns": [
            "encounter_id",
            "master_definitions_id"
        ]
    },
    medication_prescriptions: {
        "label": "medication_prescriptions",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": false,
        "icon": "\uf486",
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.75) + seperator, "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.6)},
        "columns": [
            "encounter_id",
            "master_definitions_id"
        ]
    },
    side_effects_has_medication_prescriptions: {
        "label": "side_effects_has_medication_prescriptions",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": false,
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.65) + seperator, "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.45)},
        "columns": [
            "encounter_id",
            "master_definitions_id"
        ]
    },
    medication_regimen: {
        "label": "medication_regimen",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": false,
        "icon": "\uf484",
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.85) + seperator, "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.15)},
        "columns": []
    },
    medication_prescription_has_medication_regimen: {
        "label": "medication_prescription_has_medication_regimen",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": false,
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.85) + seperator, "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.3)},
        "columns": []
    },
    medication_dispensations: {
        "label": "medication_dispensations",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": false,
        "icon": "\uf490",
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.65) + seperator, "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.3)},
        "columns": []
    },
    medication_adherences: {
        "label": "medication_adherences",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": false,
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.65) + seperator, "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.15)},
        "columns": [
            "master_definitions_id"
        ]
    },
    lab_orders: {
        "label": "lab_orders",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": false,
        "icon": "\uf0c3",
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.85) + seperator, "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.6)},
        "columns": [
            "encounter_id",
            "master_definitions_id"
        ]
    },
    lab_test_results: {
        "label": "lab_test_results",
        "color": "orange",
        "fixed": false,
        "icon": "\ue597",
        "pos": {"x": Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 0.85) + seperator, "y": Math.floor(window.innerHeight * 0.75)},
        "columns": []
    },
},
edges: {
    people: {
        person_addresses: {},
        de_duplicator: {},
        person_has_type: {},
        person_names: {},
        occupation: {},
        contact_details: {},
        hiv_staging_infos: {},
        soundexes: {},
        de_identified_identifiers: {},
        identifiers: {},
        outcomes: {},
        potential_duplicates: {},
        relationships: {},
        encounters: {},
    },
    person_types: {
        person_has_type: {}
    },
    master_definitions: {
        relationships: {},
        outcomes: {},
        vitals: {},
        presenting_complaints: {},
        patient_histories: {},
        diagnosis: {},
        symptoms: {},
        breastfeeding_statuses: {},
        side_effects: {},
        medication_prescriptions: {},
        lab_orders: {},
        medication_adherences: {}
    },
    encounters: {
        hts_results_given: {},
        family_plannings: {},
        pregnant_statuses: {},
        appointments: {},
        vitals: {},
        presenting_complaints: {},
        patient_histories: {},
        diagnosis: {},
        symptoms: {},
        breastfeeding_statuses: {},
        side_effects: {},
        medication_prescriptions: {},
        lab_orders: {}
    },
    side_effects: {
        side_effects_has_medication_prescriptions: {}
    },
    medication_prescriptions: {
        side_effects_has_medication_prescriptions: {},
        medication_dispensations: {},
        medication_prescription_has_medication_regimen: {}
    },
    medication_regimen: {
        medication_prescription_has_medication_regimen: {}
    },
    lab_orders: {
        lab_test_results: {}
    },
    medication_dispensations: {
        medication_adherences: {}
    }
}
```

};

Below is my canvas which I have referenced and am able to draw something simple as a circle and then return the canvas and draw on my screen like below:

```
const myCanvas = ref()
const ctx = myCanvas.value.getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
```

I am new to graphs and data structures but what I intend to do is use that data and draw nodes and edges between those tables enclosed in circles and displaying the table name which is the `label` in the JSON data. Anyway I can achieve this like below?

[image]

I want the `name`, `first_name` etc to be the labels in the graphs and connecting the tables like such with arrows pointing to the the other table. Is this possible with a canvas and this JSON data?

Comment: Try https://gojs.net/